# NGINX Returns 404 for Non-Subdomain, While WWW Subdomain Works Fine

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

The title really explains it all. When I request my website at `www.protolauncher.net`, it works fine. However, when I request it at `protolauncher.net`, it only returns the php file. Every other file, such as my `style.css`, is returning 404. I am at a complete loss at this point. Here's my current configuration:

```
# HTTPS
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    root /home/www-data/protolauncher.net/www/public/;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name www.protolauncher.net protolauncher.net;

    # Security
    include security.conf;
    ssl_certificate ssl/protolauncher.net.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key ssl/protolauncher.net.key;

    # Locations
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ /\.(scripts|modules) {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.(ht|git) {
        deny all;
    }
}

# HTTP
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name www.protolauncher.net protolauncher.net;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

The files are located at `/home/www-data/protolauncher.net/www/public/`. The weird thing is, I do not have this issue with my other domain, `visualfiredev.com`, which uses an identical script. I'm really hoping you guys will be able to help me out, thanks in advance :)

EDIT: Also, to specify, this ONLY happens when using `https`. `http` properly redirects me like it's supposed to. (ex. `https://protolauncher.net` errors, while `https://www.protolauncher.net` does not)

Comment: Have you cleared the browser's cache since updating the Nginx configuration?

Comment: Interesting, I thought I did, but I guess I didn't. Thanks!